# warning: passing argument 1 of 'numberWithBool:' with different width due to prototype

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uikit

The compiler complains about this, after I activated all kind of warnings:

I create an NSNumber like this:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'numberWithBool:' with different width due to prototype

it complains about the value I provided. What's wrong with "YES"?
What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have turned on one of the über-anal warnings about type coercion related to size changes.   The compiler is complaining -- likely erroneously, from what I can tell -- that YES is being converted from one width to another -- from 8 bits to 32, most likely.

Turn off that particular warning.  There are a number of compiler warnings that have grown to be effectively useless over the years.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing -Wconversion, or if that's not there, adding -Wno-conversion

Answer (score 1):

Remove `-Wconversion`

See man (1) gcc